# Some numbers greater than 2 will not be removed from the list

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-requests

This code removes numbers greater than 2 for a low number of inputs, but when the number of inputs increases, it does not remove numbers greater than 2, I wanted to know the reason ???

code :

```
x = int(input())
list = []
for i in range(x) :
    m = int(input())
    list.append(m)
for i in list :
    if i > 2 :
        list.remove(i)
print(list)
print(len(list))
z = len(list) / 3
print (int(z))
```

Entrance :
41
5,3,3,1,1,2,5,0,1,3,1,1,4,2,0,3,1,3,3,4,4,1,2,0,5,3,3,1,0,5,0,1,2,2,1 ,0,2,5,0,4,2

Output :
[1, 1, 2, 0, 1, 1, 1, 2, 0, 1, 3, 1, 2, 0, 3, 3, 1, 0, 0, 1, 2, 2, 1, 0, 2, 0, 4, 2]
28
9

Comment: Don't delete items from a list while you are iterating it.  Instead, build a new list with the items that pass.  `lst = [i for i in lst if i <= 2]`.  And don't name a variable `list`.  That conflicts with the built-in type name.

Answer (score 0):

because remove function remove single element not all from the list.

try it:

```
x = int(input())
list= []
for i in range(x) :
    m = int(input())
    list.append(m)
while(1):
    flag=1
    for j in list:
        if j>2 :
           list.remove(j)
           flag=0
    if(flag):
        break
print(list)
```